# Bootstrap and Panel Heading Color in SCSS for rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Fledgling programmer working through the onemontrails tutorials.  Its providing me with a crash course in Ruby, Rails, and some CSS.  I'm working with Devise and Panels to make my app look presentable.  Outside of the tutorial, I tried changing the default colors to make my site look different.  I'm storing the changes in a SCSS file.  Using a combination of the tutorial, google, and bootstrap documentation, I have been able to change the coloring for most everything, EXCEPT the panel header and footer.

If I follow some of the previous examples I have done for the jumbotron element, I successfully changed the panels bg color, but not the heading color;

```
$panel-bg: #E87E04;
$panel-heading-bg: #E87E04;
```

Bootstrap documentation for other CSS elements had how to change the color for headings, but I'm just not seeing it for panel headers.  Most of the googling I'm doing is providing me with information I am not clear on how to use with my SCSS file. I found many references to use

```
.panel-title
```

Just not sure how to relate that to my SCSS.  Can someone provide me with an example to what I am trying to accomplish, or links to the documentation I can't seem to find?

Comment: Create a bootstrap_override.css.scss file and add all the styles that you want to override and then require that file in application.css file. Make sure you have required it below bootstrap

Comment: Hi Mandeep,  I do have a SCSS file that is functioning correctly.  I'm having a problem figuring how how to control that panel header :)

Comment: can you show me which panel you are talking about, some link or anything?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely long delay.  Took me a long time to figure out how to get my app up on Heroku and Heroku working with Windows (Came down to a bad ssh key, and not using the GIT shell on Windows).

http://arcane-basin-8400.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in

Notice the header and footer of the panel aren't stylized like the rest of the panel?  I'm trying to figure out how to control that in Bootstrap.

Comment: No issues. Rails on windows is kinda tough. If your app isn't working then you can make a fiddle and show your code there :). IF you are overriding it then i suspect it could be a css specificty issue

Comment: Sorry it didn't show me your edited version and hence no link. Just checked your app and noticed you have `background-color: whitesmoke;` on **.panel-footer** and **.panel-default>.panel-heading**. I'm able to change colors so what is the issue?

Comment: this is where my newness shines; so I have that .scss file.  In there, it looks like this;

    $body-bg: #F7CA18;
    $text-color: #EEEEEE;

How do I make those changes in the SCCS file?  And sorry for the edits, not use to having to shift enter for a new line.

Comment: if you have defined your variables properly then you should be able to use them by doing `background: $body-bg;`

Comment: I haven't defined any variables, all part of Bootstrap I thought?  Is bootstrap defining the variables for me?

Comment: which gem are you using for bootstrap? You said `$body-bg: #F7CA18; $text-color: #EEEEEE;` so thought you would have defined those variables and i don't think bootstrap does, you have to define your own variables

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to recompile the `.scss` into `.css` so that your changes are taken into effect. 
You will have to use SASS and in terminal, `cd` to where your files are and then

`sass --update input.scss:output.css`

if you do not recompile then the css will not be updated, thus missing declarations.